# How to push data in nested array in angular JS and then later sort the whole data together

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Below is my HTML page, i am trying to fetch data from controller and display on page, later an user submits the comment ad the comments gets added to existing data and to be sorted by either date, author or rating.

i am getting an undefined error on push while doing this. where am i going wrong

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="DishDetailController">
    <div class="row row-content" ng-repeat="food in dish">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="media" >
                <div class="media-left media-middle">
                    <a href="#">
                    <img class="media-object"
                     ng-src={{food.image}} alt="Uthappizza">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h2 class="media-heading">{{food.name}}
                     <span class="label label-danger label-xs">{{food.label}}</span>
                     <span class="badge">{{food.price | currency}}</span></h2>
                    <p>{{food.description}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-1">
            <h4>Customer comments &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp <small>  Sort by <input type="text" ng-model="sortBy"></small></h4>

            <ul class="list-unstyled">
             <li>
            <blockquote ng-repeat="commen in food.comments|orderBy:sortBy">
            <p>{{commen.rating}} Stars</p>
              <p>{{commen.comment}}</p>
              <footer>{{commen.author}}  <cite>{{commen.date| date:'mediumDate'}}</cite></footer>
            </blockquote>
            </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-1" ng-controller="DishCommentController">
                <ul class="list-unstyled" ng-show="commentForm.$valid && submitted">
                    <li>
                    <blockquote>
                        <p>{{putComment.rating}} Stars</p>
                         <p>{{putComment.comment}}</p>
                       <footer>{{putComment.author}}, <cite>{{putComment.date| date:'mediumDate'}}</cite></footer>
                     </blockquote>
                    </li>
               </ul>
            <form class="form-horizontal" name="commentForm" ng-submit="submitComment()" novalidate>
                <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error' : commentForm.fullName.$error.required && !commentForm.fullName.$pristine }">
                    <label for="fullName" class="col-sm-2 control-label"> Your Name </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fullName" id="fullname" ng-model="putComment.author" required>   
                        <span ng-show="commentForm.fullName.$error.required && !commentForm.fullName.$pristine" class="help-block">Your Name is required.</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label"> Number of Stars </label>
                 <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="stars" value="1" ng-model="putComment.rating">1</label>
                    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="stars" value="2" ng-model="putComment.rating">2</label>
                    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="stars" value="3" ng-model="putComment.rating">3</label>
                    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="stars" value="4" ng-model="putComment.rating">4</label>
                    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="stars" value="5" ng-model="putComment.rating">5</label>
                 </div>
               </div>
                <div class="form-group" ng-class= "{'has-error': commentForm.feedback.$error.required && !commentForm.feedback.$pristine }">
                    <label for="feedback" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Your Feedback</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="feedback" name="feedback" rows="12" ng-model="putComment.comment" required>
                        </textarea>
                        <span ng-show="commentForm.feedback.$error.required && !commentForm.feedback.$pristine" class="help-block">Comments are required.</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="commentForm.$invalid">Submit Comment</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

below is my controller code. Also i get undefined when i log on console this-console.log($scope.dish.comments) while i get data for this console.log($scope.dish)

```
    .controller('DishDetailController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

           $scope.sortBy="";

            var dish = [
                         {
                          name:'Uthapizza',
                          image: 'images/uthapizza.png',
                          category: 'mains', 
                          label:'Hot',
                          price:'4.99',
                          description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
                           comments: [
                               {
                                   rating:5,
                                   comment:"Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
                                   author:"John Lemon",
                                   date:"2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:4,
                                   comment:"Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
                                   author:"Paul McVites",
                                   date:"2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:3,
                                   comment:"Eat it, just eat it!",
                                   author:"Michael Jaikishan",
                                   date:"2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:4,
                                   comment:"Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
                                   author:"Ringo Starry",
                                   date:"2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:2,
                                   comment:"It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
                                   author:"25 Cent",
                                   date:"2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               }

                           ]
                      }
            ];

            $scope.dish=dish;
        }])


        .controller('DishCommentController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
         $scope.submitted=false;


         $scope.putComment = { rating:5, comment:"", author:"", date:"" };

        $scope.submitComment = function () {


        $scope.putComment.date= new Date().toISOString();

        console.log($scope.putComment);
        console.log($scope.dish.comments);

        $scope.dish.comments.push($scope.putComment);

          $scope.commentForm.$setPristine();

          $scope.submitted=true;

         $scope.putComment={rating:5, comment:"", author:"", date:""};

            } 
         }]);
```

Comment: dish array assign to $scope.dish in a one controller and ur pushing to $scope.dish in a another controller.   u need to either combine the controllers or use a service to communicate between controllers

Comment: @Ranawaka, there is a commentForm on the web page for registering user comments. i am trying to push the newly written comments in the comments array in the dish array , thats why two separate controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got this working by changing the following code :

```
$scope.dish.comments.push($scope.putComment);
```

to below one

```
$scope.dish[0].comments.push($scope.putComment);
```